# AttributeError in Python object has no attribute

Tags: attributes, attributeerror

i Keep getting the attribute error for "add" but i have added it in the Calculator file. any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Your indentation is wrong*, put the `add()` and the other methods on the same level as `__init__()` method.